# Is it possible to encode an integer to byte array to be binary comparable

Tags: hadoop, integer, byte, comparator

I wanted to check if there was a way of encoding an integer into bytes that would be binary comparable.

Example: say I have integers -1 and 1

a) Write -1 to byte array b1[], write 1 to b2[]

b) b1[] should compare less than b2[]

If we write in big endian order I believe it works for positive integers but not negative ones.

I am trying to do this for a Hadoop custom raw key comparator...

Thanks

Ajai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in C#, but you should be able to do something similar to this in your language of choice, it'll give you the correct sort order for positive as well as negative integers.
Note that you need to use an *unsigned* byte type to sort correctly.

```
static byte[] EncodeToBytes(int val)
{
    val -= int.MinValue;
    var result = new byte[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++, val <<= 8)
        result[i] = (byte)(val >> 24);
    return result;
}

static int DecodeFromBytes(byte[] val)
{
    var result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        result = (result << 8) | (val[i] & 0xff);
    return result + int.MinValue;
}
```

Comment: @Ajai It shifts the integer so that MinInt becomes 0 and MaxInt becomes MaxUInt (that is, all numbers will be positive instead of half positive, half negative) and then it encodes it big endian into the byte array. Decode does the reverse, decodes from big endian and shifts the numbers back down.